# How can I draw a line from one point to a list multiple points

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm quite new(ish) to python, so sorry if my syntax is basic or just downright bad.

I'm trying to create a simple 2D Line of Sight script where one point draws a line to all the other points using Matplotlib.

[list of points in Matplotlib](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OO9p9.png)

Currently, I have a list of points, but I'm having trouble writing the For loop for it. My idea was to create a For loop to draw the lines from the origin to all the x,y coords as defined in positions, but it unfortunately doesn't work.

```
quality = 5
x = np.linspace(-1,1,quality)
y = np.linspace(-1,1,quality)
X,Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)

positions = np.vstack([Y.ravel(), X.ravel()])

plt.scatter(*positions[::-1])
plt.show()

origin = [0,0]

for i in range(len(positions)):
    for j in range(len(positions[i])):
        x1 = positions[0][j]
        y1 = positions[1][j]
        line = shapely.geometry.LineString([origin, [x1, y1]])
```

[But when i run this script, all i get is this output.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3eq6U.png)

What I'm trying to accomplish is something similar to the image below that I've done in another software.

[points connect to all points](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w4rMT.png)

Comment: What output does this give you? or what error are you receiving when you run it?  Please explain why it doesn't work.

Comment: @DavidCollins i've added the output of the script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'shapely' is something I've never used before, but I've tried to recreate it by introducing a live riley, and I had to assign the coordinate information on shapely to a variable in matplotlib. The answer I was referring to is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54498791/split-a-linestring-at-each-point-it-crosses-a-polygon-in-shapely).

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from shapely.geometry import LineString

quality = 5
x = np.linspace(-1,1,quality)
y = np.linspace(-1,1,quality)
X,Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)

positions = np.vstack([Y.ravel(), X.ravel()])

plt.scatter(*positions[::-1])

origin = (0, 0)

for i in range(len(positions)):
    for j in range(len(positions[i])):
        x1 = positions[0][j]
        y1 = positions[1][j]
        line = LineString([origin, (x1, y1)])
        x2, y2 = line.xy
        plt.plot(0, 0, x2, y2)

plt.show()
```

[image]